# Transformation of geometry on select Postgresql

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, postgresql, postgis-2.2

I am trying to run a transformation of a geom via a select query, the layer has been digitised in WGS 4326 and when I run my select to filter the table by my criteria, I would like to transform the CRS from WGS84 (4326) to UTM36S (32736)

My final Query is designed make a new table of attributes from the first changing the CRS 4326 - 32736

I have two steps I cannot seem to join

```
SELECT ST_AsText(geom) FROM foo  which provides the list of geoms as text
MULTIPOLYGON(((32.841274 -25.151649,.............32.841274 -25.151649)))
```

And with the resultant Text entered in:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOLYGON(((32.841274 -25.151649,.............32.841274 -25.151649)))',4326),32736)) As wgs_geom;
```

I get the result:

```
MULTIPOLYGON(((484002.707664207 ............... 7218250.78539813)))
```

But:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText FROM (SELECT ST_AsText(geom) FROM foo) ,4326),32736)) As wgs_geom;
```

or

```
SELECT ST_AsText FROM a (ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText FROM (SELECT ST_AsText(geom) FROM foo) as a ,4326),32736)) As wgs_geom;
```

doesn't run I've spent a bit of time looking at the syntax of the SQL but can't get it to run...

Any Ideas?

Note: the MULTIPOLYGON are quite complex hence ..........

Answer (score 1):

First off:

- You can chain most functions directly if their return types are compatible, so no need to subselect within a function
- Geometries in textual representation are merely a tool for readability, so no need to have them translated in intermediate steps

- Your understanding of the SQL syntax is...problematic, as is the
  notation ,). Get a good read on general SQL query structure, the
  [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_intro.asp) for example offer a quite comprehensive introduction

But, to help you out here; if I assume correctly that you simply want all geometries in table `foo` transformed into the given projection, and the original geometries are correctly referenced to a CRS, try

```
SELECT ST_Transform(geom, 32736) AS utm_geom
FROM foo;
```

to get the binary representation of your transformed geometries (standard format used for storage and geometric analysis within PostGIS) for further tasks, or

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Transform(geom, 32736)) AS utm_geom
FROM foo;
```

to get a simple textual representation of your geometries.
If you´d like to create a new table with those geometries, use

```
CREATE TABLE bar AS
  SELECT ST_Transform(geom, 32736) AS utm_geom
  FROM foo;
```

(I need to add here: creating tables like above is trivial, maintaining performant database/table structures is not. Among *a lot* of other things, for one of the next steps in learning PostgreSQL/PostGIS I recommend to read about indexes/table statistics and performance in general)

Filters are most commonly added in the `WHERE` block, like

```
SELECT ST_Transform(geom, 32736) AS utm_geom
FROM foo
WHERE ST_IsValid(geom);       --Note: this is equal to 'WHERE ST_IsValid(geom) = TRUE'
```

to select only those rows/geometries of table `foo` that are well formed.

Note: in all cases, these queries will only return your geometries, no other column will be added to either the output or the table. To add more columns, name them in the `SELECT` command, possibly before the geometry, like

```
SELECT <column_a> AS <new_name_for_a_if_needed>,    --repeat for other columns if necessary
       ST_Transform(geom, 32736) AS utm_geom
FROM foo;
```

Comment: @Terry you´re welcome! one more thing: as a (still somewhat) new user to this board, consider taking the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to get aquainted with formatting code etc. in questions and how to possibly reward helpful answers by upvoting/accepting...